# Windows 7 in Active Directory can not modify services

Tags: windows, active-directory

I had a windows 7 enterprise client joining in my Active Directory. I found I can not start the iscsi initiator app when I login as a domain user. I also found the Microsft iSCSI Initiator Service is manual, and gray in my services. I can not start, stop, or modify the services.

So, I think this maybe a problem with AD, how can I found the solution?

BTW, my account login in to win7 is domain user in Administrators group.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. Because in default, domain account are not local administrators, just add them to local administrators group in domain policy  will solve this.